# Proving a block matrix is psd.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices

I have a special matrix $X \in \mathbb R^{2n \times 2n}$ whose all elements are non-negative.

The matrix is in a block structure: $X = \begin{pmatrix} X^1 & X^2 \\ X^3 & X^4  \end{pmatrix}$ where $X^1 = \mathrm{diag}(x_1, x_2, \ldots,x_n)$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ and $X^4 = \mathrm{diag}(y_1, y_2,\ldots,y_n)$ for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}_+$, e.g., the diagonal blocks are diagonal matrices. Moroever, $X^2$ is a matrix whose $i$-th row sums to $x_i$, and $j$-th column sums to $y_j$. Similarly, $i$-th row of $X^3$ sums to $y_i$ and $j$-th column of $X^3$ sums to $x_j$.

An example matrix for $n= 2$ would be: $\begin{pmatrix} 0.3061 & 0  & 0 &  0.3061 \\
   0 & 0.6939  &  0.0826  &  0.6112 \\
   0 & 0.0826  &  0.0826  &  0 \\
    0.3061 &   0.6112   & 0 &   0.9174 \end{pmatrix}.$

I would like to show that such an $X$ (in general, not this example above) is positive semi-definite. I don't know if it helps, but I have $\sum_i x_i = 1, \sum_j y_j = 1$.

Comment: The closest I can think of is to use something like Gershgorin circle theorem, but I think that would require something more extreme (diagonals need to be at least as large as the sum of the absolute values of the off-diagonals).

Comment: @Y.S.  thanks for your idea! The values are non-negative, and sum of off-diagonals and sum of diagonals are equal to each other by definition. Does this help?/

Comment: Wait, so can you write $A_{kk}\geq \sum_{i\neq k} |A_{ik}|$ for all $k$? I think that may be off by a factor of 2 based on what you constructed.

Comment: @Y.S. yes, isn't it? Because rows of $X^2$ sum to the corresponding diagonal element in $X^1$. Same for rows of $X^3$ vs. $X^4$.

Comment: Ok! Then the circle theorem should apply! You basically argue that all the eigenvalues must be in a range of $[A_{kk} - \sum_{i\neq k}|A_{i,k}|, A_{kk}+ \sum_{i\neq k}|A_{i,k}|$, and since that's always a positive range, you're done!

Comment: @Y.S. wow, that would make perfect sense! I can accept this as an answer if you post it (and if it is correct, but I think it is!)

Comment: For future reference, "Diagonally dominant matrices" might be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use [Gershgorin Circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

**Thm**: For a symmetric $m\times m$ matrix $A$ with diagonal elements $A_{ii}$, $i = 1,...,m$ the eigenvalues of $A$ lie in the union of sets $[D_{ii}-R_i, D_{ii}+R_i]$ where $R_i = \sum_{i\neq j}|A_{ij}|$.

So, if you can guarantee that for all rows $i$, the quantity $R_i \leq D_{ii}$, then you can ensure that $$\text{eigenvalues}(A) \geq \min_{i=1,...,m} D_{ii}-R_i \geq 0$$ hence, the matrix is PSD!